# Possible problems deleting /tools in LFS

Tags: binary, lfs, toolchain

I recently made a Linux From Scratch and now I want to delete the /tools directory. But before rushing through it, I ran

> ldd /bin/* | grep '/tools'

Which gave me this

> liblzma.so.5 => /tools/lib/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fd7e82f9000)
>   libpthread.so.0 => /tools/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd7e7ec3000)
>           libc.so.6 => /tools/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd7e7b1f000)
>           liblzma.so.5 => /tools/lib/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f2ff2852000)
>           libpthread.so.0 => /tools/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2ff241c000)
>           libc.so.6 => /tools/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2ff2078000)

I then manually checked the output of `ldd` and found out

> /bin/kmod:
>           linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd71dbd000)
>   
> liblzma.so.5 => /tools/lib/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f14721ab000)
>           
> libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f1471f92000)
>           
> libpthread.so.0 => /tools/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1471d75000)
>           
> libc.so.6 => /tools/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f14719d1000)
>           
> /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f14723d0000)

and

> /bin/lsmod:
>          
>  linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcc1db7000)
>           
> liblzma.so.5 => /tools/lib/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f3cb7285000)
>           
> libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f3cb706c000)
>          
>  libpthread.so.0 => /tools/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3cb6e4f000)
>           
> libc.so.6 => /tools/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3cb6aab000)
>           
> /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3cb74aa000)

Looks like it's only referring to `/tools` in case of only `kmod` and `lsmod`
I checked other entries, and they are all pointing to the right ones. For example

> /bin/lzcat:
>           
> linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdee0db000)
>           
> liblzma.so.5 => /lib/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007ff6cb537000)
>           
> libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff6cb31a000)
>           
> libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff6caf76000)
>           
> /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff6cb75c000)

Note that, here all of them are pointing to `/lib`.

So should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe.

The `ldd` output contains the names of the libraries that the binary will use *after* searching the library search path. If you have some configuration that points to your `/tools` directory (e.g., `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or an `ld.so.conf` entry), then try removing that. If `ldd` doesn't point to your `/tools` directory after you've done so, you should be fine.

If it does, then your binaries are probably compiled with an `RPATH` set. An `RPATH` is a hardcoded location for a shared library that is stored into the compiled binary. It can be useful in some edge cases, but in your situation it would be decidedly unhelpful. If it is set, there is a tool called `chrpath` with which you can change or remove it.

Comment: There is no $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and no reference of /tools in ld.so.conf